# project skipping my if statement? Java

Tags: java, if-statement

So starting out, i am new to java. Very new. I decided to make my own program tonight and 6hrs later I have almost got there. My program is to launch a combo box, depending on which thing you select and when you click the button it is supposed to set that to a string. It then compares the string in an if statement and writes to a file according to it being true or false. Expect for I cant seem to make it write as if the statement was true. Im having issues with the debugger. Here is my code :

```
String[] realms = {"Choose a realm", "True-WoW", "Eternal-WoW"};
JComboBox RealmList = new JComboBox(realms);
JButton button = new JButton("Change Realmlist and Launch WoW");
JLabel label = new JLabel("Realms: ");
JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Made by: Ian D");

String chosenRealm;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    WoWRealmlist classInstance = new WoWRealmlist();
    classInstance.comboBox();
    classInstance.changeRealm();
    //classInstance.runWoW();

} //End of main

public void comboBox() {

    RealmList.setSelectedIndex(0);

    JFrame f = new JFrame("WoW Realm Chooser");
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(300, 150);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(label);
    p.add(RealmList);
    p.add(button);
    p.add(label3);

    f.add(p);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            chosenRealm = RealmList.getSelectedItem().toString();
            label2.setText(chosenRealm);


        } //End of actionPerformed

    }); //End of button.addActionListener

} //End of comboBox

public void changeRealm() {

    if ("True-WoW".equals(chosenRealm)) {

        File f = new File("E:\\Prgram Files\\WoW Wrath of the Lich King\\Data\\enUS\\", "realmlist.wtf");
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f, false);
            fw.flush();
            fw.write("set realmlist login.truewow.org");
            fw.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        } //End of catch

    } //End of if
    else {
        File f = new File("E:\\Prgram Files\\WoW Wrath of the Lich King\\Data\\enUS\\", "realmlist.wtf");
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f, false);
            fw.flush();
            fw.write("set realmlist logon.eternal-wow.com");
            fw.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        } //End of catch`
```

`chosenRealm` should equal "True-WoW" and make my if statement true.

Comment: Try debugging your code with a debugger (every IDE has one). Or, for start, add `System.out.println("Chosen realm: " + chosenRealm)` before `if` statement.

Comment: Are you sure that you are assigning the value to your instance ? , If you are having problems with debugger just debug manually using print statements , Just check what value are assigned to ur instance

Comment: Predrag, it prints out 'null', but isnt that because i have clicked the button yet?

Comment: Actually, yes :) You should call `changeRealm()` from button's action listener, and remove it from `main'.

Comment: So i did that and it waits till i click on the button, but when i click true-wow on the drop down and then click the button still prints null :(

Sorry for noobish ability of programming xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you set chosenRealm is:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        chosenRealm = RealmList.getSelectedItem().toString();
        label2.setText(chosenRealm);


    } //End of actionPerformed
```

Which means, whenever you click the button, it's going to set chosenRealm. And you call `changeRealm` method which uses if within main, and at that point in time, your chosenRealm would be still having default value i.e. null and hence you dont enter the if condition.

I would suggest you move call to `changeRealm` method only when you click button and then write to a file.

Comment: SMA, so you are saying move my "classInstance.changeRealm();" to below the 'button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()' ???

Comment: Yes just statement after you assign chosenRealm variable a value.